# How to notice that WebView loaded all iframes

Tags: android, html, webview

How can I determine that all javascripts have been loaded in android WebView.
I need to read html of webview but after  javascript have been loaded otherwise I will not get what I need.

Answer (score 0):

There is no provided interface to directly say that all `JS` scripts have loaded. However, here is the only way to know that the content of a `WebView` is loaded:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // do what you want
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I think I found what I need. Its exists. I will debug it and update a soon.